# direcciones de DNS configurar dominio

Tags: dns, dominio, ip

engo un dominio K.net en empresa X y el servidor lo tengo en casa en IP publica "A.B.C.D:PPPP" ya que mi IP es estatica y tengo puesto en el DNS de la empresa X esta configuración

```
www  60 IN TXT    "http://A.B.C.D:PPPP/wiki/"  
     60 IN TXT    "http://A.B.C.D:PPPP/wiki/"
```

al poner la barra del navegador K.net pues entra a la web pero se ve el la dirección "http://A.B.C.D:PPPP/wiki/index.php"
mi propósito es que se viera http://K.net/index.php

una opción he visto es

```
www  60 IN A    "A.B.C.D"  
     60 IN A    "A.B.C.D"
```

pero no puedo poner puerto ni directorio interno del servidor

¿¿que otras opciones de configuraciones de DNS puedo utiliza para lograrlo ??
la empresa X es OVH si alguien ha echo alguna configuración similar, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema no es del DNS, sino del Servidor Web, al momento de ingresar a tu servidor web existe alguna regla del tipo Rewrite o RewriteCond que esta colocando la IP.

Sobre el DNS, los registro del tipo TXT son informativos, no sirve de nada que lo pongas con www. El registro WWW se debe usar como un **CNAME**.

Por otro lado si estas atrás de un ISP no te va servir levantar el DNS, ya que cuando hagan consultas desde el Exterior la resolución las responde el ISP. Necesitarías pedirle a tu ISP te cediera el control de la Zona, lo cual no va hacer.

Solo podrás usar tu DNS Server para resoluciones dentro de tu intranet/red local.